# Rendering issue using Android Studio 0.4.0

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I recently decided to try Android Studio after being a while on Eclipse. My main activity xml rendered okay on Eclipse but Studio seems to have a problem with it. It reports this on the Preview window: Rendering Problems java.lang.StackOverflowError Copy stack to clipboard.

Part of the contents (full is > 70K characters) of the clipboard is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:153)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
```

The actual xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/currentPosition"
    style="@style/ScreenFont_Normal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#F7F7E6"
    android:textColor="#8B8B8B"
    android:text="@string/curr_loca" />

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/currentPosition"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_main"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Although this does not affect the build and creation of the .apk file I would still like to take advantage of the cool graphical UI editing features of Studio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Is the name of that xml file, @layout/activity_main, because if that is so, then it's the problem. You are recursively loading the fragment into itself with that tools:layout attribute

Comment: Yikes, it absolutely is. I'll remove it and get back

Comment: That improved things quite a bit. I can now see the render but a new error is reported:Rendering Problems A <fragment> tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.
- <fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment ...> (Pick Layout...)
 Do not warn about <fragment> tags in this session If I choose the activity_main.xml layout(which I am assuming is the correct one)it puts the tools:layout attribute backagain

Comment: Yep ... not sure what your question is. But that is expected, since you are no longer specifying what the fragment looks like.

Comment: I guess the question is which activity do I pick (to make the error go away) other than activity_main(which I assume is the correct one but causes the original error to return if I choose it)

Comment: This is a warning it's not an error. It's not going to preview a map for you. Probably best to submit a new question if you have one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the following line from the XML inside your fragment:

`tools:layout="@layout/activity_main"/>`

Reason: In Android Studio, you're presented with an option to edit separate layouts when working with an XML document containing a fragment. **Upon selecting the option to edit the parent layout, this line above is inserted into the code.** Cheers