# StackOverflow when trying to render with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, stack-overflow

I am trying to develop an app based on the Google Maps activity, and when trying to view the layout in Android Studio it reports that there is a rendering error and that there has been a Stack Overflow, the details of which are shown below:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:160)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:117)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    ...
```

I'm new to Android Development on the whole, and don't really understand why this is not working. I've attached a screenshot below to help illustrate the problem:

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Is there anything on how to fix this kind of problem, my research hasn't found anything. I am running version 1.0.2 of Android Studio.

Comment: Looks like Android Studio Bug...

Comment: @Mou Is there anything that I could do to fix this bug, or at least, a workaround?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810919/rendering-issue-using-android-studio-0-4-0

Comment: @Mou I hadn't seen that, thank you; but removing the line results in another error: `A <fragment> tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.`

Comment: @Mou Never mind, it's just a warning

Comment: Is it possible you have a circular reference in your xml layout code? Make sure that there aren't two view depending on each other, as it will cause a stack overflow.